# I am getting an "is not a function" error in spite of passing the function correctly through props to another component and using it there in react

Tags: reactjs, async-await

The function in the component list.js :

```
const getArrData = async () => {
    console.log("from cat list")
    await axios
      .get('http://localhost:8080/itemreq/getallireq')
      .then((res) => {
        const newData = res.data.map((user) => ({
          itemReqId: user.itemRequisitionId,
          itemName: user.requiredItem.itemName,
          quantity: user.quantity,
          status: user.reqStatus.reqStatusName,
          requiredBy: user.requiredByDate,
          reason: user.reason
        }));
        setTableData(newData.reverse());
        console.log('Item Category data ============>', res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  };
```

Passing this function through props:

```
<ItemCategoryQuickEditForm
                open={quickEdit.value}
                onClose={quickEdit.onFalse}
                getArrData={getArrData}
              />
```

Now I am calling this function in 2 handlers in the "ItemCategoryQuickEditForm". These handler are used in if-else for either edit or create from the same form. Now in the Create handler the await getArrData() is getting called perfectly and giving me the expected output. But when the same getArrData() is called in the update handler, I am getting an error that "getArrData() is not a function".
I am providing the handlers bellow.

Destructuring the prop:

export default function ItemCategoryQuickEditForm({ currentUser, open, onClose, getArrData})

Update handler:

```
 const handleUpdate = async (data) => {
    const itemreq = {
      requiredItem: selectedItem,
      reason: data.reason,
      quantity: data.quantity,
      requiredByDate: data.requiredby,
    };
    console.log('getarrdata---------------------', getArrData);
    const url = `http://localhost:8080/itemreq/updateitemreq/${data.item}`;
    await axios.put(url, itemreq);

    onClose();
    await getArrData();
    enqueueSnackbar('Update success!');
  };
```

Create Handler:

```
const handleCreate = async (data) => {
    const itemreq = {
      requiredItem: selectedItem,
      reason: data.reason,
      quantity: data.quantity,
      requiredByDate: data.requiredby,
    };

    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/itemreq/addreq';
    await axios.post(url, itemreq);
 reset();
    setselectedItem(null);
    onClose();
    await getArrData();
    enqueueSnackbar('Requisition Created Successfully!');
  };
```

I am putting these 2 handlers in if-else in the onsubmit handler
OnSubmit handler:

```
const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async (data) => {
    try {
      if (currentUser) {
        await handleUpdate(data);
      } else {
        await handleCreate(data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  });
```

What I want to do is to all the getArrData function in both the create and update handler. So that the pop-up form that I am using closes and the list behind rerenders so the changes reflect in the list. The function call is working perfectly when I am creating and the createhandler is called. But when i update and the HandleUpdate is called, the error "getArrData() is not a function is showing up".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried commenting this console log line? It exists in the handleUpdate object but not the other. The function call await getArrData(); is the same in both so that doesn't seem like an issue to me.

console.log('getarrdata---------------------', getArrData);

Perhaps a way to help debug further would be to change temporarily one or more of your functions from arrow operator to regular function. That way you can see the stacktrace better during run and see where it stopped/the error occured.

Comment: I have commented the log but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Try changing from arrow function to regular function declarations where you can and test again.